# How can I grep Intellij's build time notifications - which log file has these?

Tags: intellij-idea, logging, build, grep

Can anyone help me figure out how to obtain a list of logged build times from Intellij? A search on the web and in S.O. didn't enlighten.

My intellij IDEa reports java project build times in the *Event Log* window like so:

```
Build completed successfully with 1,750 warnings in 5 min, 20 sec
```

I wanted to grep these notifications to see how my build times have evolved recently (e.g. to see an improvement after excluding certain folders from the antivirus realtime scans).

I found these logfiles under JetBrains folders:

```
$ find /c/Users/myuser/AppData/*/JetBrains -type f -name \*log
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/database-log/database.0.log
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/log/build-log/build.log
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/log/idea.log
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/logs/toolbox.log
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/statistics/events.log
```

But none of them contains the build time notifications.

Any tips appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same duration is printed in [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory) file as the following pattern:

```
2021-09-14 15:30:34,030 [105340589]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -   COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 4299 ms: 0 min 4sec
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for gradle because it logs length of the build in console `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 23s`, not sure about other build tools. But yes, there is a way to get all information from console during your build to be written to a file, you have to enable it for your run configurations.

Go to `Run/Debug Configurations` > `Modify options` > tick `Save console output to file`, after that the field is going to appear that lets you specify the file path under `Save console output to file` like on the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a gradle entry - probably don't have the plugin. Thanks for the the screenshot though, always helps. I didn't know you can setup custom log files (+1).